# HTTP Live Streaming encoders

Tags: http, streaming, live

I'm developing an iPhone app which helps you stream videos from IP camera into your iPhone. Here I need to use HTTP Live streaming. I wanted to know about any encoders required to convert ip camera output to MPEG-2 transport stream. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound obvious but you could push the camera stream to some media server [like Wowza](http://www.wowza.com), and transcode it to HLS there easily. HLS is "native" for iOS so your iPhone won't be having any troubles with playback.